# how to find a particular log from a server for one particular time and zip logs for only that time

Tags: linux, grep, logging

I have got a command for the above question. Could anyone please explain me the below command?

```
DATE=`date +%m%d%Y-%H%M%S` ; for i in `ls -lt *.log* | grep "Oct 11" | grep -E '12:|13:|14:' | awk '{print $9}'`; do zip logs_`hostname`_${DATE}.zip $i; done
```

Answer (score 0):

The script you are referring to is not well written at all and might not work as you expect.

Here is the breakdown of what is it doing:

> DATE=`date +%m%d%Y-%H%M%S`

Store current date in DATE in a format like "10192016-171249". Refer to "man date" for details.
This, by the way, is not the best way to store a date/time. Using the format YYYYMMDD for the date portion is much prefered for quick reference/sorting reasons.

> ls -lt *.log*

That gets a directory listing of all files matching the pattern "*.log*" in the current directory. 
For example, it could be something like:

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  174106 Sep 30 17:28 dpkg.log.1
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    1642 Oct 11 12:28 fontconfig.log
-rw-r----- 1 root adm   272254 Oct 11 11:28 kern.log.4.gz
-rw-r----- 1 root adm   272254 Oct 11 17:14 kernXX.log.1.gz
-rw-r----- 1 root adm      414 Sep 29 18:09 user.log.4.gz
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root     209 Sep 26 14:18 chipsee_clone.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    1333 Apr  9  2015 pm-powersave.log.1
```

> grep "Oct 11"

Then it "extracts" only the lines where "Oct 11" is present, which would give:

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    1642 Oct 11 12:28 fontconfig.log
-rw-r----- 1 root adm   272254 Oct 11 11:28 kern.log.4.gz
-rw-r----- 1 root adm   272254 Oct 11 17:14 kernXX.log.1.gz
```

> grep -E '12:|13:|14:

Then it extracts again only those where "12:" or "13:" or "14" is present:
(again very poorly done as this applies the hours field, but to minutes and seconds fields too)

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    1642 Oct 11 12:28 fontconfig.log
-rw-r----- 1 root adm   272254 Oct 11 17:14 kernXX.log.1.gz
```

> awk '{print $9}'

From those remaining lines, it extracts the 9th element (the file name):

```
fontconfig.log
```

> zip logs_`hostname`_${DATE}.zip $i

Using a "for" loop around the above command, each of those files is then added to a zip file which name is:

```
logs_`hostname`_${DATE}.zip
```

where `hostname` is the name of your host and "${DATE}" is the DATE stored earlier.
So if your host name is BLUERAY and using the DATE above, you get a file named:

```
logs_BLUERAY_10192016-171249.zip
```

Again, this script is very poorly written and you certainly should not use
it (or any other written by the same author) to learn how to write scripts...